# different function and variable on single Datatable

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datatables

a little help please.

I am using [datatables](http://datatables.net/) in my wordpress project and I need to do two different functions and required different variable. The first function is to add index/rank in the first column, and the second one is to filter the active content of the second column. But datatables plugin wont allow it and will send an alert message.

The error is triggered by passing in options to a DataTables constructor object when the DataTable instance for the selected node has already been initialised.

Can someone show me how to do this?
any help will be much appreciated

Currently, Here's my Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = $('#dt').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": 0
        } ],
        "order": [[ 7, "desc" ]],
    } );

    t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
        t.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i+1;
        } );
    } ).draw();
} );



$(document).ready(function() {
  otable = $('#dt').dataTable({
    "bSortCellsTop": true,
    "order": [[ 7, "desc" ]],
  });
})

function filterme() {
  //build a regex filter string with an or(|) condition
  var types = $('input:checkbox[name="Category"]:checked').map(function() {
    return '^' + this.value + '\$';
  }).get().join('|');
  otable.fnFilter(types, 1, true, false, false, false);

  //use radio values
  var frees = $('input:radio[name="free"]:checked')[0].value;
  otable.fnFilter(frees, 2, false, false, false, false);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can manage using custom db define in query section.

Comment: Hi @PPL, can u elaborate a little

Comment: First My question is you want to  display records from different database.

Comment: nope, its from a single database. then data is display through the tables. the first column just have different function on the second column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it work already. I just have to call a plain function

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = $('#dt').DataTable( {
        "bSortCellsTop": true,
        "order": [[ 7, "desc" ]],
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": 0
        } ]
    } );

    t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
        t.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i+1;
        } );
    } ).draw();
} );



$(document).ready(function() {
  otable = $('#dt').dataTable();
})

function filterme() {
  //build a regex filter string with an or(|) condition
  var types = $('input:checkbox[name="Category"]:checked').map(function() {
    return '^' + this.value + '\$';
  }).get().join('|');
  //filter in column 0, with an regex, no smart filtering, no inputbox,not case sensitive
  otable.fnFilter(types, 1, true, false, false, false);

  //use radio values
  var frees = $('input:radio[name="free"]:checked')[0].value;
  //now filter in column 2, with no regex, no smart filtering, no inputbox,not case sensitive
  otable.fnFilter(frees, 2, false, false, false, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems here:

1. You've got a couple of `$(document).ready(function() {` blocks, you should consolidate this down to just one.
2. You're initialising the same DataTable ('#dt') twice, with different arguments. That's not possible, you can only do it the once. It would be better to move the `"bSortCellsTop": true,` into the first initialisation. You can then just make oTable `otable = $('#dt').DataTable()` - without the options it's not initialising the table, it's just getting the handle. Note also the casing in that second initialisation, currently it's giving you a jQuery handle, not a DataTables (I corrected that in the last example).